# X X^T Matrix is not positive definite, although it should be

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra

I have a matrix `M` where `M.shape = (679, 512)`.

I would like to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of `M M^T`, it's covatiance matrix, which should be positive definite in maths. I find them using:

```
import numpy as np
v, w = np.linalg.eig(np.matmul(M, M.T))
```

However, for some reason I see my eigenvalues/eigenvectors as:

```
>>> v
array([ 1.17577206e+10+0.0000000e+00j,  1.05090161e+10+0.0000000e+00j,
        7.01098189e+09+0.0000000e+00j,  5.19451802e+09+0.0000000e+00j, 
    ...
    1.03985971e-12+0.0000000e+00j, -3.04194468e-13+6.9097571e-13j,
   -3.04194468e-13-6.9097571e-13j,  1.77363116e-13+0.0000000e+00j,
   -1.20885913e-13+0.0000000e+00j, -4.95627438e-14+0.0000000e+00j,
   -1.56456859e-16+0.0000000e+00j], dtype=complex64)
```

How is this possible? Shouldn't `M M^T` be positive semi definite, giving positive and real eigenvalues only? How is it possible to get non real eigenvalues?

```
def is_positive_def(x):
    return np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(x) > 0)
```

Comment: I don't really know the exact answer, but given that all of the negative values are *very* small, I strongly suspect this has something to do with numerical roundoff issues.

Comment: The min eigenvalue is 
`(-284.69064+0j)`

Comment: Can you add an example matrix to the question? All the negative eigenvalues you show are very very small, and I got the same when trying it with a random array generated with `np.random.randn(630,512)`.

Comment: @user545424 The edit was large and buggy, but here is the file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/15YSKCDIohJYrBXMw8pFiVXaOa2qYRZ07/view?usp=sharing which can be loaded using `np.load`

Comment: It would be nice if you could reproduce it with something easy to create (i.e. using `np.random` or something else). The short answer to your question is that if you know your matrix is symmetric you should be using `np.eigh`.

Comment: I guess it's some error in the matrix itself, I just don't seem to understand what could potentially cause it. In any way, thanks a lot

Comment: Did you subtract the mean from your matrix? The covariance matrix of X is `X*XT - mu*muT`. So maybe `Mc = M - M.mean(axis=0); v, w = np.linalg.eig(np.matmul(Mc, Mc.T))` yields the expected result.

Comment: @josemz This is it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Shouldn't M M^T be positive semi definite, giving positive and real eigenvalues only?"*  If you change "positive" to "nonnegative", then yes, that is true mathematically.  In fact, instead of [`numpy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html), you can use [`numpy.linalg.eigh`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html), which will return real eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Note that in a few places, you misstated that claim, and said that M M^T is positive definite.  That is not correct.  If M has shape (679, 512), then 679 - 512 = 167 of the eigenvalues will be 0; M M^T is semi-definite, not [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix).

In the numerical computation of the eigenvalues, all those theoretical values of 0 will not be computed exactly by `eig` or `eigh`.  The first 167 eigenvalues will be *close* to zero, and numerical error can result in some of those values being negative.  When I did the calculation on a random M (specifically, `M = np.random.gamma(8, size=(679, 512))`, the largest eigenvalue of M M^T was about 2.227e7, the smallest was -5.822e-10, and the smallest magnitude was 3.881e-13.  Note that 5.822e-10/2.227e7 (i.e. `np.abs(v.min()) / v.max()`) is about 2.61e-17, so all those small eigenvalues are effectively 0 *relative to the largest eigenvalue*.